# Ansible unable to find .my.cnf Can't connect to local MySQL server

Tags: ansible

Since 6 hours I'm trying to find out how ansible wants to work with my mariadb on ubuntu 16.

When I manually log in on the server with

> mysql -u someuser -p

everything works fine

when I try to access the server with the ansible script with:

```
  - name: Create mysql database
    mysql_user: name=someuser state=present password=somepw
```

its complaining:

> fatal: [IP]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true,
>   "msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and
>   login_password are correct or /home/someuser/.my.cnf has the
>   credentials. Exception message: (2002, \"Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)\")"}

Then I try to put .my.cnf into the directory on the remote server like it is trying to tell me.
I also added login_user and login_password. No help.

The file looks like this:

/home/someuser/.my.cnf

```
 [client] 
 user=someuser
 password=somepw
```

"Okay" I thought. Maybe the credentials are doubled in the ansible script and in the conf file. I tried to leave the conf file or to skip the credentials in the ansible script. No help

I also restarted the mysql server. No help. The strange thing is, that from the server itself everything worked with the mysql shell.
I'm really struggleing to find the solution. Shouldn't this work just like a charm?

Comment: @techraf The playbook is no script? What else is it? The ansible script (playbook) accesses the server, otherwise ansible would be senseless. (3) I know sometimes programmer tend to have not much fantasy but if I say I added it...maybe...maybe you can anticipate? Positive thinking man! Thanks for your inspiring remarks!

Answer (score 34):

Okay figured it out. Ubuntu 16 in my case puts the socket file into

> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

where ansible isn't expecting it. 
So for me it worked to put login_unix_socket into the playbook (ansible script)

```
  - name: Create mysql database
    mysql_db:
      login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
      name: projectname
      state: present
```

and place .my.cnf like mentioned above.

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04, this fixed the problem.

Comment: Same issue on Debian 11/bullseye, this fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

**Lets deep dive into the `mysql_db` module first:**

The main parameters to watch are `login_host`, `login_user`, and `login_password`.

The simplest approach (in this example, to create a db) is:

```yaml
- name: Create database
  mysql_db:
    name: "{{ the_name_of_db_to_create }}"
    login_host: "{{ the_instance_where_db_needs_creating }}"
    login_user: "{{ the_master_username_for_instance }}"
    login_password: "{{ the_master_password_for_instance }}"
    state: present
```

In this case, we do not need `$HOME/.my.conf` because the `login_user` and `login_password` takes precedence.

P.S: Be sure to use `state: present` to create db only if it does not exist.

**When do we need `login_unix_socket` then?**

The answer is in the documentation itself.

```
The path to a Unix domain socket for **local** connections.
```

Yes, only if your db instance resides in the same server where the ansible is executed against.

If you tried adding this property and tried to connect to a remote instance, it will fail with the same error message that the OP has mentioned, because this parameter seem to override `login_host` to `localhost`.

**When do we need `$HOME/.my.conf` then?**

When your git repository holding the ansible playbook is too sensitive and cannot leave details like username and password there, for any so ever reason. You can still hide behind env vars or use var files during execution, etc.. but you may decide to add the `$HOME/.my.conf` in the server manually or as a one off ansible operation. The format of the file would be:

```
[client] 
user=the_master_username_for_instance
password=the_master_password_for_instance
```

It goes without saying that when this file is added, the parameters `login_user` and `login_password` are not necessary.

**What happens when I neither mention parameters nor the conf file?**

Ansible will then try with username `root` and no password.

---

**Now, lets see how to create a new user using `mysql_user` module**

Note that the module is used for more than just creating a new user. But this is by far this is the most sought out functionality.

The simplest approach is:

```yaml
- name: Create user
  mysql_user:
    name: "{{ the_name_of_user_to_create }}"
    login_host: "{{ the_instance_where_db_needs_creating }}"
    login_user: "{{ the_master_username_for_instance }}"
    login_password: "{{ the_master_password_for_instance }}"
    state: present
```

All the parameters follow the same rules as above in the mysql_db module.

**Now, this will create `user@'localhost'`. What if you want to create `user@'some_other_host'`?**

Here it is:

```yaml
- name: Create user
  mysql_user:
    name: "{{ the_name_of_user_to_create }}"
    password: "{{ the_password_for__the_new_user }}"
    login_host: "{{ the_instance_where_db_is }}"
    login_user: "{{ the_master_username_for_instance }}"
    login_password: "{{ the_master_password_for_instance }}"
    state: present
    host: "{{ the_client_host }}"
```

Note you can use `%` for the `the_client_host` to allow access from anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

> Requires the MySQLdb Python package on the remote host. For Ubuntu, this is as easy as apt-get install python-mysqldb. (See apt.) For CentOS/Fedora, this is as easy as yum install MySQL-python. (See yum.)
>
> Both login_password and login_user are required when you are passing credentials. If none are present, the module will attempt to read the credentials from ~/.my.cnf, and finally fall back to using the MySQL default login of ‘root’ with no password

After that please use below code to connect with DB:

```
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    password: deepak
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Please verify your socket file from `my.cnf` and update it.

If you are running your playbook from remote_host, you might get error 

    `"msg": "unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or /home/********/.my.cnf has the credentials. Exception message: (1045, \"Access denied for user '********@'localhost' (using password: NO)\")"`

To resolve this you have to allow remote host connection to mysql.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using CentOS and in CentOS the sock path is completely different than even I thought,

Found the path with

```
ps -ef | grep mariadb
```

Finally the issue got fixed as below,

```
   - name: Create database
     mysql_db:
        name: "{{ db_name }}"
        state: present
        login_unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I know this was a quite old question. I faced the same recently and thought this might be helpful for some one who is after the same.

Answer (score 1):

> **unable to find /root/.my.cnf. Exception message**

**When did I got this error.**

```
- name: "Mysql Configuration - Resetting RootPassword"
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: ''
    name: root
    host: localhost     <<===================== Cause of Error.
    password: "{{mysql_root_password}}"


- name: "Mysql Configuration - Creating Wordpress Database"
  mysql_db:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{mysql_root_password}}"
    db: "{{wp_database}}"
    state: present
```

> fatal: [centos-client.ansible.lab]: FAILED! => {"changed": false,
>   "msg": "unable to find /root/.my.cnf. Exception message: (1045,
>   \"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)\")"}

** This Is How I Fixed It**

```
- name: "Mysql Configuration - Resetting RootPassword"
  mysql_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: ''
    name: root
    host_all: yes     <<=====================  Fix
    password: "{{mysql_root_password}}"


- name: "Mysql Configuration - Creating Wordpress Database"
  mysql_db:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{mysql_root_password}}"
    db: "{{wp_database}}"
    state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in some distribution like ubuntu you may want to use login_unix_socket in order to specify the exact location of mysql socket.

Answer (score 0):

It worth to note that ansible **only takes login and password** from `.my.cnf` file. So if you have `.my.cnf` like this:

```
[client]
host=10.0.0.4
user=root
port=3310
password=strongpassword

[mysql]
database=irk
```

It allows you to easily connect to mysql from console just typing `mysql`.

But for ansible you have to specify host and port in playbook file:

```
- mysql_user:
    ...
    login_host: 10.0.0.4
    login_port: 3310
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [@Jurudocs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44615595/14318474) and [@fuji-komalan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55167266/14318474), use the `login_unix_socket` module argument and possibly add `host_all: yes`.

This is my final configuration:

```yaml
- name: Change root password for MariaDB
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    password: <password>
    login_unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    host_all: yes
```

- The path is `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` instead of `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
- The argument `host_all` is used and set to `yes`

Google said that

> On CentOS / RHEL / Rocky Linux, the default socket file is `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.

This works for me on AL2023.